# ansible template custom src lookup.first_found

Tags: ansible

How to change the value of `src` to use the first file found or use another path/file if none is found ignoring errors, for example, I want to have a file for a specific host, but default to another file if the first one is not found or skip, I can solve this by duplication the following block with a different `src` each:

```
- name: create file unique per host:
  template: 
    src: "{{ ansible_host }}/{{ item }}.conf.j2"
    dest: "/etc/wireguard/{{ item }}.conf"
  loop: "{{ files }}"

- name: create file:
  template: 
    src: "{{ item }}.conf.j2"
    dest: "/etc/wireguard/{{ item }}.conf"
  loop: "{{ files }}"
```

In the role directory, I have inside the templates a directory per host (IP), for example:

```
roles/
  `templates/
    | default.conf.j2
    `10.1.2.3/
      |wg.100.conf.j2
      `wg.200.conf.j2
```

When the task runs against `10.1.2.3` I want to use the files `wg.100.conf.j2` & `wg.200.conf.j2` but for other hosts use `default.conf.j2` or skip if nothing is defined

Any idea how to do it in a single task?
For example, I would like to call the playbook like this:

```
- roles:
  - role: test_role
    configs:
      - wg.test-1
      - wg.test-2
```

The expected result is to have the files `wg.test-1` and `wg.test-2` in all hosts:

1. `/etc/wireguard/wg.test-1.conf`
2. `/etc/wireguard/wg.test-1.conf`

But also include unique files per `host`, for example having the following structure within the role, host `10.1.2.3` will have the files `wg.100` & `wg.200` and host `10.1.2.4` the file `wg.300`

```
      test_role
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            ├── 10.1.2.3
            │   ├── wg.100.conf.j2
            │   └── wg.200.conf.j2
            ├── 10.1.2.4
            │   └── wg.300.conf.j2
            │ 
            ├── wg.test-2.conf.j2
            └── wg.test-1.conf.j2
```

The reason I want to do all within a task is to simplify the restart of only changed services despite if the `src` is different and use something like:

```yaml
- name: create config
  template:
     src: "{{ ansible_host }}/{{ item }}.conf.j2"  ||  {{ item }}.conf.j2
     dest: "/etc/wireguard/{{ item }}.conf"
  loop: "{{ configs }}"
  notify: restart service
  register: changes

- set_fact:
    restart_service: "{{ restart_service | default([]) + [item.item] }}"
  when: item.changed
  loop: "{{ changes.results }}"
  no_log: true
```

This is the current working role that I have, but would like to find a better approach (prevent duplicating blocks)

```yaml
---
- name: Create wg.file
  template:
    src: "{{ item }}.conf.j2"
    dest: "/etc/wireguard/{{ item }}.conf"
  loop: "{{ vpns }}"
  notify: restart vpn
  register: changes

- set_fact:
    restart_service: "{{ restart_service | default([]) + [item.item] }}"
  when: item.changed
  loop: "{{ changes.results }}"
  no_log: true

- name: find per host wg.files
  set_fact:
    per_host_wg_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'templates/{{ ansible_host }}/*.j2', wantlist=True) }}"

- name: Create per host wg.files
  template:
    src: "{{ ansible_host }}/{{ item | basename }}"
    dest: "/etc/wireguard/{{ (item | basename).split('.')[:3] | join('.') }}"
  loop: "{{ per_host_wg_files }}"
  notify: restart vpn
  register: changes

- name: create fact with changes
  set_fact:
    restart_service: "{{ restart_service | default([]) + [(item.item | basename).split('.')[:2] | join('.')] }}"
  when: item.changed
  loop: "{{ changes.results }}"
  no_log: true
```

Just in case this is the restart handler:

```yaml
- name: restart vpn
  systemd:
    daemon_reload: true
    state: restarted
    enabled: true
    name: "wg-quick@{{ item }}"
  async: 10
  poll: 5
  loop: "{{ restart_service }}"
  when: restart_service is defined
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example 1.**

Given the tree for testing

```bash
shell> pwd
/scratch/tmp7/test-151
```

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    └── role_A
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            ├── 10.1.2.3
            │   ├── test-1.conf.j2
            │   └── test-2.conf.j2
            ├── 10.1.2.4
            │   └── test-2.conf.j2
            └── default.conf.j2

6 directories, 8 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host1 ansible_host=10.1.2.3
host2 ansible_host=10.1.2.4
host3 ansible_host=10.1.2.5
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  vars:
    files: [test-1, test-2, test-3]
    findme: "{{ [ansible_host]|
                product(files|
                        product(['.conf.j2'])|
                        map('join'))|
                map('join', '/') + ['default.conf.j2'] }}"
    found_file: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.first_found', found_params) }}"
    found_params:
      files: "{{ findme }}"
      paths: ['templates']
      skip: true
  roles:
    - role_A
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role_A/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: findme
- debug:
    var: found_file

- name: Do it in this single task
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', found_file) }}"
```

```bash
shell> cat roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/test-1.conf.j2 
10.1.2.3 test-1
shell> cat roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/test-2.conf.j2 
10.1.2.3 test-2
shell cat roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.4/test-2.conf.j2 
10.1.2.4 test-2
shell> cat roles/role_A/templates/default.conf.j2 
{{ ansible_host }} default
```

---

1. Create a list of files. Declare the variables

```yaml
  files: [test-1, test-2, test-3]
  findme: "{{ [ansible_host]|
              product(files|
                      product(['.conf.j2'])|
                      map('join'))|
              map('join', '/') + ['default.conf.j2'] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [role_A : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [host3] => 
  findme:
  - 10.1.2.5/test-1.conf.j2
  - 10.1.2.5/test-2.conf.j2
  - 10.1.2.5/test-3.conf.j2
  - default.conf.j2
ok: [host1] => 
  findme:
  - 10.1.2.3/test-1.conf.j2
  - 10.1.2.3/test-2.conf.j2
  - 10.1.2.3/test-3.conf.j2
  - default.conf.j2
ok: [host2] => 
  findme:
  - 10.1.2.4/test-1.conf.j2
  - 10.1.2.4/test-2.conf.j2
  - 10.1.2.4/test-3.conf.j2
  - default.conf.j2
```

---

2. Find the first file available.

- The plugin [*first_found*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/first_found_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-first-found-lookup-return-first-file-found-from-list) by default doesn't look for files in *templates*. You must add this subdirectory to the parameter *paths* when you put files into *templates*.
- The lookup below always succeeds because each list of files is terminated by *default.conf.j2*.
- `skip: true` means the lookup returns an empty list `[]` when no files are matched.

```yaml
    found_file: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.first_found', found_params) }}"
    found_params:
      files: "{{ findme }}"
      paths: ['templates']
      skip: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [role_A : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [host2] => 
  found_file: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-151/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.4/test-2.conf.j2
ok: [host3] => 
  found_file: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-151/roles/role_A/templates/default.conf.j2
ok: [host1] => 
  found_file: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-151/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/test-1.conf.j2
```

---

3. Use the file.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', found_file) }}"
```

If you want to allow an empty variable *found_file* test it

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('template', found_file) }}"
  when: found_file|length > 0
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [role_A : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    10.1.2.3 test-1
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    10.1.2.4 test-2
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: |-
    10.1.2.5 default
```

---

**Example 2.**

Q: ***"Given the following structure within the role, the expected result is to have the files `wg.test-1` and `wg.test-2` in all hosts and also include unique files per host. Host 10.1.2.3 will have the files `wg.100` and `wg.200`, and host 10.1.2.4 the file `wg.300`."***

```yaml
      test_role
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            ├── 10.1.2.3
            │   ├── wg.100.conf.j2
            │   └── wg.200.conf.j2
            ├── 10.1.2.4
            │   └── wg.300.conf.j2
            │ 
            ├── wg.test-2.conf.j2
            └── wg.test-1.conf.j2
```

A: In this case the plugin *first_found* is not needed. Use the plugin *fileglob* instead.

Given the tree for testing

```yaml
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    └── role_A
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yml
        └── templates
            ├── 10.1.2.3
            │   ├── wg.100.conf.j2
            │   └── wg.200.conf.j2
            ├── 10.1.2.4
            │   └── wg.300.conf.j2
            ├── wg.test-1.conf.j2
            └── wg.test-2.conf.j2
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - role_A
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role_A/defaults/main.yml 
files_global_pattern: templates/*.j2
files_global: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.fileglob', files_global_pattern) }}"
files_local_pattern: "templates/{{ ansible_host }}/*.j2"
files_local: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.fileglob', files_local_pattern) }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role_A/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: |
      files_global:
      {{ files_global|to_nice_yaml }}
      files_local:
      {{ files_local|to_nice_yaml }}
      
- debug:
    msg: |
      src: {{ item }}
      dest: {{ _dest }}
      content: {{ lookup('template', item) }}
  loop: "{{ files_global + files_local }}"
  vars:
    _dest: "{{ item|basename|splitext|first }}"
```

```bash
shell> find roles/role_A/templates -type f | xargs cat
{{ ansible_host }} wg.test-1
{{ ansible_host }} wg.test-2
10.1.2.3 wg.200
10.1.2.3 wg.100
10.1.2.4 wg.300
```

---

1. Declare the lists of global and local files

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role_A/defaults/main.yml 
files_global_pattern: templates/*.j2
files_global: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.fileglob', files_global_pattern) }}"
files_local_pattern: "templates/{{ ansible_host }}/*.j2"
files_local: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.fileglob', files_local_pattern) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [role_A : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    files_global:
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2
  
    files_local:
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/wg.200.conf.j2
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/wg.100.conf.j2
[WARNING]: Unable to find 'templates/10.1.2.5' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: |-
    files_global:
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2
  
    files_local:
    []
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    files_global:
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2
  
    files_local:
    - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.4/wg.300.conf.j2
```

---

2. Use the lists

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      src: {{ item }}
      dest: {{ _dest }}
      content: {{ lookup('template', item) }}
  loop: "{{ files_global + files_local }}"
  vars:
    _dest: "{{ item|basename|splitext|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [role_A : debug] ************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Unable to find 'templates/10.1.2.5' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)
ok: [host1] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2
    dest: wg.test-1.conf
    content: 10.1.2.3 wg.test-1
ok: [host2] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2
    dest: wg.test-1.conf
    content: 10.1.2.4 wg.test-1
ok: [host1] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2
    dest: wg.test-2.conf
    content: 10.1.2.3 wg.test-2
ok: [host2] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2
    dest: wg.test-2.conf
    content: 10.1.2.4 wg.test-2
ok: [host3] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-1.conf.j2
    dest: wg.test-1.conf
    content: 10.1.2.5 wg.test-1
ok: [host2] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.4/wg.300.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.4/wg.300.conf.j2
    dest: wg.300.conf
    content: 10.1.2.4 wg.300
ok: [host1] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/wg.200.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/wg.200.conf.j2
    dest: wg.200.conf
    content: 10.1.2.3 wg.200
ok: [host3] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/wg.test-2.conf.j2
    dest: wg.test-2.conf
    content: 10.1.2.5 wg.test-2
ok: [host1] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/wg.100.conf.j2) => 
  msg: |-
    src: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-152/roles/role_A/templates/10.1.2.3/wg.100.conf.j2
    dest: wg.100.conf
    content: 10.1.2.3 wg.100
```

---

Q: ***"How do you prevent the error: 'ansible_host' is undefined?"***

A: Use *default* if you want to allow undefined variable. For example,

```yaml
files_local_pattern: "templates/{{ ansible_host|d('udefined') }}/*.j2"
```

The result will be the warning below

> [WARNING]: Unable to find 'templates/udefined' in expected paths

Comment: If instead of passing the files how could I list(include) all the files that exist already per `ansible_host` so that I could then only pass a list of "defaults" but always include what is within the dir `ansible_host/*.conf.j2` ?

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. Show an example of the file tree and the expected result.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question and added more context hope it helps

Comment: You don't need *first_found* for this. I added an example.

Comment: How do you prevent the error: `{"msg": "{{ q('ansible.builtin.fileglob', files_local_pattern) }}: templates/{{ ansible_host }}/*.j2: 'ansible_host' is undefined. 'ansible_host' is undefined. templates/{{ ansible_host }}/*.j2: 'ansible_host' is undefined.`

Comment: Use *default*. I added an example.

Comment: in my case all are remote hosts, `ansible_host` exists, works for example if using: `"{{ lookup('fileglob', 'templates/{{ ansible_host }}/*.j2', wantlist=True) }}"` but not if using it as a variable in `defaults/main.yml`

Comment: You're wrong. `"{{ }}"`  can not be nested. Open new questions if you have problems. We're done. here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251124/discussion-between-nbari-and-vladimir-botka).

Comment: It works, give it a try and check the code I am using `per_host_wg_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'templates/{{ ansible_host }}/*.j2', wantlist=True) }}"` in defaults using `ansible_host` doesn't work probably because: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21269